# How to fully erase windows 8 and install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I'm looking to buy a new laptop or desktop this year and was wondering if I should buy a computer with windows 8?  I see that every Ubuntu user that has bought a windows 8 laptop that they are having the worst time getting windows 8 removed from the hard drive.  I don't want windows at all on my computer I can't stand that greedy corporation, I just want a new computer that is easy to install Ubuntu and totally erase windows.  Can someone help me please?????

Comment: Have you researched on the internet yet? http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: @owl That's a helpful resource but it's focused on running Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. To replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu, aren't there other options? Can't UEFI simply be disabled, in some "BIOS" setups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to start off with the main issue is that Windows 8 computers have "Secure Boot"
and "UEFI". If your computer has the Bios options to enable Legacy Boot and disable Secure Boot then you should be able to easily install any Linux Distro. Refer to these for more information:

- http://www.zdnet.com/hp-pavilion-dm1-4310-ssd-installation-and-fun-with-efi-boot-7000008168/
- http://www.zdnet.com/more-fun-with-windows-8-uefi-secure-boot-fedora-and-ubuntu-7000009292/

Comment: After reading through all that fun stuff, I think I'll just go buy a computer from system76, computers made with Ubuntu installed and save myself the hassle.  Had enough of reading for today.lol.  thanks for all your help :)